# How to send identity documents to directly to Stripe Platform Account?

Tags: php, e-commerce, stripe-payments, payment, stripe-connect

How can I send identity documents to Stripe without the documents touching my website? I want to be able to send the documents directly to Stripe. I do not want the documents saved on my website even for a millisecond. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use stripe.js for the upload?

Comment: *"**Please do not downvote**"* = *"Please downvote"*

Comment: @Robert I took a look at Stripe.js but I didn't see how to send verification documents with it. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: @Memor-X I am hoping people still have respect for one another and know not to downvote for fun like some people like to do.

Comment: Why would they need to send verification documents to a site that isn't yours and how would you utilise such a verification process? Surely if they're sending docs to Stripe then Stripe aren't going to show you anything they've sent and if they need to send them to Stripe, they'll feel safer just using Stripe directly, no?

Comment: @GCRDev Stripe needs verification documents in order to help with their verification process and payment solutions. This how Stripe works: https://stripe.com/docs/ . Hope this helps!

Comment: i know how stripe works, I just don't see why anyone would want to send their private and personal documents through you. It would sound dodgy to anyone you put it to. Anyone with a hint of common sense would just think you're trying to scam them

Comment: @GCRDev I don't know. Some people sign up for Uber, Lyft and the other services that need information from you. Lyft uses Stripe as well.